Azure DevOps yaml pipeline: Using output variables in conditions does not evaluate correctly
Im trying to create an output variable that will be later used for other jobs. However there is a chance that the job responsible for its creation gets skipped. To recover from this scenario I tried appending "placeholder" to the variable mentioned earlier. Later stage however does not seem to evaluate not equal condition correctly
#Here is the base pipeline:
trigger: none
pool: '<?>'
parameters:
- name: 'String'
  type: string
  displayName: 'String'
- name: 'skipA'
  type: boolean
  displayName: 'Skip stage A'
  default: false

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    condition: ne('${{ parameters.skipA }}', true)
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Run script 1'
      name: script1
      inputs:
        pwsh: true
        filePath: 'outputVariables\scripts\simpleScript.ps1'
        arguments: >-
          -inputValue ${{ parameters.String }}


- stage: B
  variables:
    myVar: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['script1.myVar'] ]
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Run script 1'
        name: script1
        inputs:
          pwsh: true
          filePath: 'outputVariables\scripts\simpleScript.ps1'
          arguments: >-
            -inputValue "placeholder,$(myVar)"
  - job: B2
    steps:
      - template: 'templateFile.yml'
        parameters:
          somethingElse: '$(myVar),placeholder'

#templateFile.yml:
parameters:
  - name: 'somethingElse'
    type: string

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    condition: ne('${{parameters.somethingElse}}', ',placeholder') #NOT EVALUATED CORRECTLY
    displayName: 'Run script 3'
    name: script1
    inputs:
      pwsh: true
      filePath: 'outputVariables\scripts\simpleScript.ps1'
      arguments: >-
        -inputValue "${{parameters.somethingElse}}"
  
  - script: echo step 2.1


#ps1 script:
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$inputValue = "Def val"
)

# Print the input value to the screen
Write-Output "You entered: $inputValue"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar;isOutput=true]$inputValue"

I expect the B2 job not to run the simpleScript

Hi there, Welcome to SO. We are unable to correctly evaluate the parameter value generated at runtime in template expression ${{ parametes }} which gets processed at compile time, before runtime

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT, thanks for reaching out so quickly. Is there a possible workaround I could try or should I give up on this approach?

Yes, I will share a working YAML syntax for your reference in the answer section shortly.

By the way, your actual requirement is NOT to run simpleScript in B2 when the input value of ${{parameters.String}} is an empty string that makes the value of $(myVar) is an empty string, right?

yes that is correct

but not when parameters.String is not empty string but when the job A1 job gets skipped, thus resulting in empty string in $(myVar) [I hope it makes sense]

That makes sense, but is just a little confusing that you have defined the parameter skipAto skip the job A1 rather than the stage A. Anyways, the solution below should work for you. Please let us know your test results. Appreciate your time and efforts.

Based on the description, you would like to generate the value for the  variable myVar output in script at pipeline runtime and pass it into templateFile.yml as a parameter. However, we should not evaluate the parameter value in template expressions ${{parameters}} which get processed at compile time, before runtime. See this document to help us Understand variable syntax
Instead of evaluating a parameter which can only be referenced in template expressions, we should opt to define newVar in runtime expressions $[variables] and evaluate its value in the condition property of a step. Here is the working YAML syntax for your reference.
basePipeline.yml
trigger: none

pool: 'Default'


parameters:
- name: 'String'
  type: string
  displayName: 'String'
  default: ''
- name: 'skipA'
  type: boolean
  displayName: 'Skip stage A'
  default: false

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    condition: ne('${{ parameters.skipA }}', true)
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Run script 1'
      name: script1
      inputs:
        pwsh: true
        filePath: 'outputVariables\scripts\simpleScript.ps1'
        arguments: >-
          -inputValue "${{ parameters.String }}"
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "MyVar is $(script1.myVar)"
      displayName: 'Check output'

- stage: B
  variables:
    myVar: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['script1.myVar'] ]
    stageDeps: $[ convertToJson(stageDependencies) ]
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Run script 2'
        name: script2
        inputs:
          pwsh: true
          filePath: 'outputVariables\scripts\simpleScript.ps1'
          arguments: >-
            -inputValue "placeholder,$(myVar)"

      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "myVar output in A1 is $(myVar)"
          Write-Host "myVar output in B1 is $(script2.myVar)"
          Write-Host "stageDeps is $(stageDeps)"
        displayName: 'Check output'
        
  - job: B2
    variables:
      newVar: $[ format('{0}{1}', variables['myVar'], ',placeholder') ]

    steps:
      - template: 'templateFile.yml'
        parameters:
          somethingElse: '$(newVar)'

templateFile.yml
parameters:
  - name: 'somethingElse'
    type: string

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    condition: ne(variables['newVar'], ',placeholder') # Evaluate the variable value generated during pipeline runtime
    displayName: 'Run script 3'
    name: script3
    inputs:
      pwsh: true
      filePath: 'outputVariables\scripts\simpleScript.ps1'
      arguments: >-
        -inputValue "$(newVar)"

  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "newVar defined in B2 is $(newVar)"
    condition:  always()
    displayName: 'Check output'


This is what I was hoping to achieve, thanks a lot.
